# Cordova App keydown event from external footswitch dosen't work on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, keyboard, phonegap, keydown

I build a Phonegap app and want to use an external footswitch via bluetooth. On Android binding the keydown Event works fine. In Browser, no Problem, but on iOS it doesn't.

I tested this variations:

```
$(document).bind('keydown',function(event)
$(window).bind('keydown',function(event)
$(document).bind('keypress',function(event)
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function (event)
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?
I tested with cli 8 and 9.

Thanks for Help

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough rep to comment so having to post this as an answer.  I believe PhoneGap's UIWebView on iOS requires input focus in order to capture keydown.  In a Cordova app I have worked on in the past, we placed an input off the screen with focus so that the input of bluetooth device would be captured and processed from there.

Recently however I have found that on an Ionic 4 app using cordova-ios 5.1.1,  WKWebView via this plugin cordova-plugin-ionic-webview and the below RXJS fromEvent I have successfully captured keydown on iOS via a bluetooth device without having to have the input.  I have not broke it down to know if this combo or any one of these has anything to do with it.  Hope this helps.

```
fromEvent(document, 'keydown').subscribe((event: KeyboardEvent) => {

});
```